# Remove HTML tag when CKEDITOR is toggled

Tags: javascript, html

I have CKEDITOR from normal textarea to ckeditor. I have a button to toggle so the user can use whether a normal text area or the ckeditor.
The problem is when I already have content in ckeditor and toggle to a normal textarea, the html tags are not removed after ckeditor has been destroyed.

Image link from CKEDITOR:
https://ibb.co/hWRgDR3

When toggled to a normal textarea:
https://ibb.co/HPKBnPP

I have tried the CKEDITOR.remove and CKEDITOR.instance.idname.destroy()

```
var ckEditorState = false; $('#editorSwitch').click(function(){
if(ckEditorState == false){
    CKEDITOR.replace('createNewTextArea');
    ckEditorState = !ckEditorState;
}else{
    var ckInstanceToRemove = CKEDITOR.instances.createNewTextArea.destroy();
    // CKEDITOR.remove(ckInstanceToRemove);
    ckEditorState = !ckEditorState;
} });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this to remove the tags `<p>...</p>` to `...` .

myString.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '');

or

myString.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');

Comment: Can you explain more where to add those?

Comment: var ckInstanceToRemove = CKEDITOR.instances.createNewTextArea.destroy();
try to get the string of this. and try to use the code above.